# How to create mysql dump of docker image from java level?

Tags: java, mysql, docker, dump

I need to create backup of docker database from java level. It should be possible using https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java. I need to run this command:

`docker exec config_mysql_1 /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=root SERVER > backup.sql`

I tried sth like this:

```java
DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance().build();
    Container container = dockerClient.listContainersCmd()
        .withNameFilter(Collections.singleton("mysql_1")).exec().get(0);

ExecCreateCmdResponse execCreateCmdResponse = dockerClient.execCreateCmd(container.getId())
        .withCmd("/usr/bin/mysqldump", "-u", "root", "--password=root", "SERVER", ">", "backup.sql").exec();
```

but nothing was created.

Comment: Most likely it ended with an error, but if that's the full code, you are ignoring all the errors. Check response's stdout and stderr.

Comment: Passing a password on the command line to mysql/mysql dump is normally `-proot` (where the password is 'root'). Sounds like security could be a bit lax too ;)

Comment: How would you do this task without Docker?  (Can you directly connect to the MySQL container's published port, without involving the Docker API?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing below statement:

```
ExecCreateCmdResponse execCreateCmdResponse = dockerClient.execCreateCmd(container.getId())
        .withCmd("/usr/bin/mysqldump", "-u", "root", "-p", "root", "SERVER", ">", "backup.sql").exec();
```

will end up writing your *MySQL* DB dump to the container ephemeral layer (assuming that the container *mysql_1* is already started and its `id` has been retrieved successfully).

To retrieve the DB backup file, you have either to mount a volume to your docker container so that your backup file gets written to your local host or either copy the generated dump using the `#DockerClient#copyArchiveFromContainerCmd`:

```
InputStream response = dockerClient.copyArchiveFromContainerCmd(container.getId(), "backup.sql").exec();
```

I suggest writing your backup file to a deterministic absolute path:

```
DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance().build();
Container container = dockerClient.listContainersCmd().withNameFilter(Collections.singleton("mysql_1")).exec().get(0);

ExecCreateCmdResponse execCreateCmdResponse = dockerClient.execCreateCmd(container.getId())
        .withCmd("/usr/bin/mysqldump", "-u", "root", "-p", "root", "SERVER", ">", "/backup.sql")
        .withTty(true)
        .withAttachStdout(true)
        .withAttachStderr(true)
        .exec();
InputStream dbDumpInputStream =  dockerClient.copyArchiveFromContainerCmd(container.getId(), "/backup.sql").exec();
// handle the `dbDumpInputStream` as per your need
```

Comment: Thank you!, great explanation! Getting dump out of the docker is handy

Comment: How about restoring the dump, i need to copy the dump to the container or can i load it from the outside?

Answer (score 1):

You must run your command.

A full example:

Be sure your mysql is up:

```
$ docker run --name mysql314 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxx -d mysql
...
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE ...
6ca86c54f335   mysql ...
```

Run:

```
DockerClientConfig standard = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder().build();
DockerHttpClient httpClient = new OkDockerHttpClient.Builder().dockerHost(standard.getDockerHost()).sslConfig(standard.getSSLConfig()).build();
DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientImpl.getInstance(standard, httpClient);
Container container = dockerClient.listContainersCmd().withNameFilter(Collections.singleton("mysql314")).exec().get(0);

ExecCreateCmdResponse execCreateCmdResponse = dockerClient
        .execCreateCmd(container.getId())
        .withPrivileged(true)
        .withAttachStdout(true)
        .withAttachStderr(true)
        .withCmd("/usr/bin/mysqldump", "-u", "root", "--password=xxxx", "--all-databases", "--result-file=/tmp/backup314.sql")
        .exec();

dockerClient.execStartCmd(execCreateCmdResponse.getId())
        .exec(new ExecStartResultCallback(System.out, System.err))
        .awaitCompletion();

InspectExecResponse rs = dockerClient.inspectExecCmd(execCreateCmdResponse.getId()).exec();
System.out.println("Exit Code: " + rs.getExitCodeLong());
```

confirm result

```
$ docker exec -it mysql314 bash
root@6ca86c54f335:/# head -n 1 /tmp/backup314.sql 
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.26, for Linux (x86_64)
```